# How to get the html Page from where I redirect to an other

Tags: php, html, redirect, squid

I'm using squidGuard to redirect an order formular from the page of a special producer to a local php script which stores the order in a DB. After storing the script sends the order via GET request to the producer.

The html site for a product of the producer looks like:
http://producer.com/products/product123

This site contains a link which calls the formular. After pressing this link our users will be redirected to our local script.

It works all fine but ...

For processing the order I need some informations which are located on the side of the product --> http://producer.com/products/product123

Is there a way to get this site (html code) whithout downloading it a second time from my php script?

EDIT 1:
OK I try to explain it a little bit better:

Site A is a site which describes a product. On this site is a link which opens a new site --> Site B

Site B is a Site which contains an order formular to order a product (or more)

When I press on the link on site A I will be redirected to a local php script on our company server which proceeds this order and stores some additional informations.
The redirection works with Squid as proxy and SquidGuard as Filter.

My problem is:
My script has to download the product page (site A) to get the additional informations.
The user who pressed the link (on site A) to order the product (on site B) has already loaded site A and it must be somewhere in squid. Maybe there is a way to get this page (site a) out of squid so that i don't have to download site a again?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but if I do you should take a look at [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents)